# Combining multiple lines of a ResultSet into a single line

Tags: mysql, sql, resultset

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        obl_books.book_id,
        obl_books.long_title,
        obl_books.short_title,
        obl_authors.first_name
FROM 
        obl_books,
        obl_authors,
        books_authors
WHERE 
        obl_books.book_id = books_authors.book_id
    AND 
        obl_authors.author_id = books_authors.author_id
    AND 
        obl_books.short_title = 'SQL'
```

It gives me 2 separate rows for each author. I want it in a single row like this:

```
Book1| SQL REFERENCE | author1 | author2 | author3
```

How can I achieve it directly in SQL query or by doing something to ResultSet result? Kindly guide. Please tell me without any PLSQL mechanism.

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If your are using MySQL try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        obl_books.book_id,
        obl_books.long_title,
        obl_books.short_title,
        GROUP_CONCAT(obl_authors.first_name, ',')
ETC...
```

Change the separator (comma) with whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Depends which rdbms, but you might try

```
SELECT DISTINCT obl_books.book_id||obl_books.long_title|| etc...
```

Or look up 'Concat()' in the help

Comment: but how would i concat author id to itself

Answer (score 0):

- Use `JOIN` instead of the old SQL-89 implicit join `WHERE` syntax
- Remove the `DISTINCT`
- Add a `GROUP BY`
- Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate all the names in one column:

  ```
  SELECT 
          b.book_id,
          b.long_title,
          b.short_title,
          GROUP_CONCAT(a.first_name
                       ORDER BY a.first_name
                       SEPARATOR ', '
                      ) AS first_names
  FROM 
          obl_books AS b
      JOIN
          books_authors AS ba
              ON  b.book_id = ba.book_id
      JOIN
          obl_authors AS a
              ON  a.author_id = ba.author_id
  WHERE 
          b.short_title = 'SQL' 
  GROUP BY
          b.book_id,
          b.long_title,
          b.short_title ;
  ```